# How to make emacs automatically spell check all visible text?

Tags: spell-checking

When flyspell is enabled it doesn't show spelling errors on all visible text *(like most text editors that support spell checking).*

When moving the cursor over text, misspelled words become underlined.

While running `flyspell-buffer` works, it's a manual operation and can be slow on large files.

Is there a way to run the spell checker on visible text, updating after scrolling?
Perhaps using delays so it doesn't make scrolling lag.

Comment: I don't like the `window-scroll-functions` hook because there are exceptions, which took me quite a bit of time to finally semi-understand [after pestering Eli and Stefan with a few bug reports ...]; and, I combined it with the `post-command-hook` to try and come up with something for all situations ....  Eventually, I took the plunge and started learning C and am now pestering Eli and Stefan on the Emacs devel mailing list instead ... :)  To see how this can work in Lisp, have a look at the `linum.el` library that has been deprecated in favor of built-in line number in Emacs 26+.

Comment: It seems the existing hooks aren't well suited to performing this operation, especially since launching a process from a timer is a no-no (gives many `Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!!` messages).

Comment: Why not just turn on the `flyspell-mode`?

Comment: @scribe because it doesn't show errors of on-screen text, only text you type or move your cursor over.

The only alternative is to run it on the entire buffer which can be slow (more than 5+ seconds on larger files).

Answer (score 4):

There are minor modes that do just this, although they don't use flyspell.

## [spell-fu](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-spell-fu)

Example use:

```el
(use-package spell-fu)
(global-spell-fu-mode)
```

## [wcheck-mode](https://github.com/tlikonen/wcheck-mode)

Example use:

```lisp
(use-package wcheck-mode
 :commands (wcheck-mode)
 :init
 (custom-set-faces
  '(wcheck-default-face ((t (:underline (:color: "red" :style wave))))))

 (setq wcheck-language-data
       '(("American English"
          (program . "/usr/bin/enchant-2")
          (args "-l" "-d" "en_US")
          (action-program . "/usr/bin/enchant-2")
          (action-args "-a" "-d" "en_US")
          (action-parser . enchant-suggestions-menu)
          (read-or-skip-faces
           ;; Only check comments & strings.
           ((emacs-lisp-mode c-mode)
            read
            font-lock-comment-face
            read
            font-lock-string-face)
           (nil)))))
 (setq wcheck-language "American English"))
```

---

## [speck-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeckMode)

Example use:

```lisp
(load "speck")
(setq-default speck-syntactic t)  ;; Only check comments and strings.
(setq-default speck-engine 'Aspell)
(setq-default speck-delay 0.1)
(setq-default speck-pause 0.1)

(custom-set-faces
  '(speck-guess ((t (:underline (:color: "red" :style wave)))))
  '(speck-miss ((t (:underline (:color: "orange" :style wave)))))
  '(speck-doublet ((t (:underline (:color: "brown" :style wave)))))
  '(speck-mouse ((t (:underline (:color: "yellow" :style wave)))))
  '(speck-query ((t (:underline (:color: "or" :style wave))))))
(setq speck-personal-dictionary-file ispell-personal-dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference: The example below runs the spell checker on a timer, however it gives many messages:

`Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!!`

.. Which I worked around by temporarily disabling logging, however this is far from ideal.

On the other hand, in practice I've found this to be usable.

---

```el
(defvar-local flyspell-visible-last-window-range nil)

(defun flyspell-visible--overlay-refresh-from-timer ()
  (when (equal flyspell-visible--delay-buffer (current-buffer))
    (let* ((sta (window-start))
           (end (window-end))
           (range (list sta end)))
      (when (not (equal range flyspell-visible-last-window-range))
        (setq inhibit-redisplay t)

        (let ((log-max message-log-max))
          ;; don't log
          (setq message-log-max nil)
          (flyspell-region sta end)
          (setq message-log-max log-max)
          (message nil))
        (setq-local flyspell-visible-last-window-range range)
        (setq inhibit-redisplay nil)))))


;; Timer
(defvar flyspell-visible--delay-timer nil)
(defvar flyspell-visible--delay-buffer nil)

(defun flyspell-visible-turn-on ()
  "Enable spell checking on a timer"
  (when (timerp flyspell-visible--delay-timer)
    (cancel-timer flyspell-visible--delay-timer))
  ;; Delay for spelling - should be ok, only runs when scroll changes.
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-buffer (current-buffer))
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-timer
        (run-with-idle-timer
         1.0 t 'flyspell-visible--overlay-refresh-from-timer)))

(defun flyspell-visible-turn-off ()
  (when (timerp flyspell-visible--delay-timer)
    (cancel-timer flyspell-visible--delay-timer))
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-timer nil)
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-buffer nil)
  (setq flyspell-visible-last-window-range nil))
```

Comment: Instead of a pair of `setq`s, just do `(let ((message-log-max nil)) (flyspell-region sta end) (message nil))`

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is not sufficient to "Add a comment", so writing in a full answer...

This is a copy-paste from ideasman42 [for reference answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50681/20077) with `flyspell-visible--overlay-refresh-from-timer` function wrapped into [`with-local-quit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting.html#index-with_002dlocal_002dquit) macro. It should solve `Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!!` messages problem.

Also, I replaced `(flyspell-region sta end)` invocation with `(let ((flyspell-issue-message-flag nil)) (flyspell-small-region start end))`:

```lisp
(defvar-local flyspell-visible-last-window-range nil)

(defun flyspell-visible--overlay-refresh-from-timer ()
  (with-local-quit
    (when (equal flyspell-visible--delay-buffer (current-buffer))
      (let* ((start (window-start))
             (end (window-end))
             (range (list start end)))
        (when (not (equal range flyspell-visible-last-window-range))
          (setq inhibit-redisplay t)
          (let ((flyspell-issue-message-flag nil))
            (flyspell-small-region start end))
          (setq-local flyspell-visible-last-window-range range)
          (setq inhibit-redisplay nil))))))

;; Timer
(defvar flyspell-visible--delay-timer nil)
(defvar flyspell-visible--delay-buffer nil)

(defun flyspell-visible-turn-on ()
  (when (timerp flyspell-visible--delay-timer)
    (cancel-timer flyspell-visible--delay-timer))
  ;; Delay for spelling - should be ok, only runs when scroll changes.
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-buffer (current-buffer))
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-timer
    (run-with-idle-timer 1.0 t 'flyspell-visible--overlay-refresh-from-timer)))

(defun flyspell-visible-turn-off ()
  (when (timerp flyspell-visible--delay-timer)
    (cancel-timer flyspell-visible--delay-timer))
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-timer nil)
  (setq flyspell-visible--delay-buffer nil)
  (setq flyspell-visible-last-window-range nil))
```

Another small improvement could be adding `flyspell` derived mode that runs `flyspell-visible--delay-timer` by default:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode flyspell-visible-mode
  "Flyspell visible mode."
  :lighter " FlyV"
  :parent flyspell-mode
  (if flyspell-visible-mode
      (progn
        (flyspell-mode 1)
        (flyspell-visible-turn-on)
        (message "Flyspell visible mode enabled"))
    (flyspell-mode -1)
    (flyspell-visible-turn-on)
    (message "Flyspell visible mode disabled")))
```