# Possible to supress the: "Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!!" message?

Tags: message, inhibit-message

When running a process from a timer, this message is printed a lot.

Is there a way to suppress the message entirely?

For reference see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50681/2418

Comment: Well the message is there for a reason -- Emacs has been told to wait for output from a process for an *unlimited duration, without allowing the user to interrupt*.  Instead of suppressing the message, perhaps it would make best sense to avoid it from being issued in the first place.

Comment: Right, this should be worked around somehow, the issue is - I have no idea how. I wanted to run a spell checker on a timer, which seems to be possible to do `wcheck` package does it, however the code is fairly complex and I'd need to spend much more time digging into it to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the answer is no.

However, this can be worked around (albeit a hack).

- Disable logging.
- Run the operation which causes the message.
- Clear the message.
- Enable logging again.

Comment: There is also `inhibit-message` (still a hack, just slightly more concise).

Comment: This happens not to work in this case, I think because the message call is from C code.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the point of `inhibit-message` is that it should work on C code, unlike advising `message` which doesn't. Although looking at its docstring, I notice `inhibit-message` doesn't inhibit logging, just the display. So if you want to keep the log clear too, it's not really that much more concise.

Comment: @npostavs `(let ((inhibit-message t) (message-log-max nil)) ...)` is the best way I know of to do both.