# How to detect when a function was activated by a timer?

Tags: timers

When running a function inside a timer, there are some constraints on whats possible.

- Adding timers should not be done (according to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html)).
- Communicating with a sub-process is limited (see [Calling flyspell from a timer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50681/2418) & [Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50680)).

---

Is it possible to detect if a function is running from a timer so an alternate code-path can be used?

The only solution I've found is to add advice on the caller to define a variable which the function being called can check, however this isn't such a nice solution as it may mean adding advice to many functions.

Comment: I guess you can see it from the call stack, which you can loop through with `mapbacktrace`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' : Is that viable at runtime? How does a (non-debugger) Lisp program go about obtaining the current call stack?

Comment: @PhilHudson Lisp programs don't need any official “debugger” blessing to call `mapbacktrace`. It will miss frames that are optimized away by the byte compiler, but that wouldn't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

All timers get processed in `timer-event-handler`, so you can add advice to that instead:

```lisp
(defvar called-by-timer nil
  "Bound to t when a function is called by a timer.")

(advice-add 'timer-event-handler :around
            (lambda (oldfun &rest args)
              (let ((called-by-timer t))
                (apply oldfun args))))

(defun hello ()
  (message "%s %s" "Hello" (if called-by-timer "from timer" "from elsewhere")))

(hello)
(run-with-timer 1 nil #'hello)
```

Comment: Should `hello` not also unset `called-by-timer` on exit?